# Use weak induction to prove the following statement is true for every positive integer $n$: $2+6+18+\dots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}=3^n-1$

Tags: induction

Use weak induction to prove the following statement is true for every positive integer $n$: $$2+6+18+\dots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}=3^n-1$$
Base Step: Prove it is true for $n$.

Inductive Hypothesis: It will be true for $n+1$

What I need to show: That it will be true for n and n+1

Proof Proper:.....

To get this started, how do I prove that it is true for $n$?  What $n$ do I choose?  The fact that there is a "..." in the equation scares me.  How do I know how to quantify $n$ and $n+1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base case is typically the least value of $n$ for which you are proving an assertion applies. Since we are aiming to prove  $$P(n):\quad 2+6+18 + \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{n-1}=3^n-1 \tag{P(n)}$$ holds for all **positive integers** $n$, we need to prove that $P(n)$ holds for $n \geq 1$, and so we need first to confirm that $P(n)$ holds for the **base case** $n = 1$.

**Base Case:**

$P(1)\; (n = 1): {\bf 2\cdot 3^{1-1}} = 2\cdot 3^0 = 2 = {\bf 3^1 - 1}\tag{base case: True}$

**Inductive Hypothesis (IH)**

Now, we **assume** that $P(k)$ is true for some arbitrary positive integer $n = k$. That is, we assume that it is *true* that $P(k):\quad 2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{k-1}=3^k-1\tag{IH}$

**Inductive Step**
Now, we will use our inductive hypothesis (IH) to prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$. So our aim is to show, using the inductive hypothesis, that $2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{k} =3^{k + 1}-1$:

$$\begin{align} P(k + 1):\quad \underbrace{2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{k - 1}}_{= \,\large 3^k - 1,\;by \;\text{IH}} + 2\cdot 3^{k} & = (3^k - 1) + 2\cdot 3^k  \\ \\ 
& = 3\cdot 3^k - 1 \\ \\ & = 3^{k + 1} - 1\end{align}$$

So we have shown, in this third step, that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$.

Hence, by induction on $n$, we can conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all integers $n \geq 1$

Comment: we have both had issues with this, so very interesting and on-point: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10133/should-moderators-intervene-when-the-accepted-answer-is-blatantly-wrong

Comment: @amWhy: Where are you right now? I see you are flying beyond the Heaven clouds.:-)

Comment: Hello, @Babak Here I am!

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the "$\dots$" scare you. Here, it just means, "continue the pattern until you get to $2\cdot 3^{n-1}$".

- For $n=4$, "$2+6+18+\cdots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}$" means $2+6+18+54$. (Stop at $2\cdot 3^{4-1}$.)
- For $n=5$, "$2+6+18+\cdots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}$" means $2+6+18+54+162$. (Stop at $2\cdot 3^{5-1}$.)
- For $n=10$, "$2+6+18+\cdots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}$" means
  $$2+6+18+54+162+486+1458+4374+13122+39366$$
- For $n=100$, it's just best to leave it as $2+6+18+\cdots+2\cdot 3^{100-1}$. By the way, this gets at the importance of formulas like the one you're proving; the "$\cdots$" notation allows us to abbreviate a sum with dozens, hundreds, *zillions* of terms, but that's just sweeping the computation under the rug; the $3^n-1$ on the formula's right-hand side tells us that this crazy-long sum can be *computed* in just two terms. How convenient!

(Note that for $n=3$, $2$, or $1$, the sum stops at the "$18$", the "$6$", or just that first "$2$". In these cases, there are more terms visible than are actually *used* in the sums. Consider that a quirk of the notation.)

---

Now, to solve the problem ... Forget about induction for a moment. Suppose I *tell* you that the formula works for $n=1,000,000$. That is, I assert that
$$2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots (999,995 \text{ terms}) \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{999,999} = 3^{1,000,000} - 1 \qquad (\star)$$ 
The numbers involved are too large for you to verify directly, so you'll have to take my word for it. *Based on that word*, can you prove that we can push $n$ one step higher? 
$$2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots (999,996 \text{ terms}) \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{1,000,000} \stackrel{?}{=} 3^{1,000,001} - 1 \qquad (\star\star)$$ 
Well, did you notice that the number of hidden terms got bigger? That's because the "$\cdots$" part of $(\star\star)$ *includes* the "$\cdots$" part of $(\star)$ *as well as* $2\cdot 3^{999,999}$, which was the last term in $(\star)$, but has become the next-to-last term in $(\star\star)$. So, we can write:
$$2 + 6 + 18 + \cdots (999,995 \text{ terms}) \cdots + 2\cdot 3^{999,999} + 2\cdot 3^{1,000,000} \stackrel{?}{=} 3^{1,000,001} - 1 \qquad (\star\star\star)$$ 
But, hey, I *told* you in $(\star)$ ---and you *believed* me, right?--- that the sum from $2$ up to $2\cdot 3^{999,999}$ has a much shorter form; therefore,
$$\left( \;\; 3^{1,000,000} - 1 \;\; \right) + 2\cdot 3^{1,000,000} \stackrel{?}{=} 3^{1,000,001} - 1 \qquad (\star\star\cdots\star)$$ 
Of course, no self-respecting algebra student would leave the left-hand side the way it is. Let's combine the $3^{1,000,000}$ terms, and ... *voila!* 
$$2\cdot 3^{1,000,000} + 3^{1,000,000} - 1 =  \left( 2 + 1 \right) \cdot 3^{1,000,000} - 1 = 3 \cdot 3^{1,000,000} - 1 \stackrel{\ddot\smile}{=} 3^{1,000,001} - 1$$

---

The thing is, there's nothing special about $1,000,000$ in the above argument. I could've asserted that the formula worked for *any* value of $n$ that I liked, and we could've used identical logic to show that the formula works for the *next* $n$. Using $1,000,000$ just gives you a specific "any value" to wrap your brain around. The number is big enough to keep you from even *considering* directly computing anything, so that you can focus on how to push "one higher"; and it's unusual enough to stick out in the argument, making it easy to convert your logic into an official "inductive step": simply replace all "$1,000,000$"s (and nearby values) with the generic "$n$" (and "$n\pm 1$", etc, as appropriate).

- Case $n$ (asserted): $2+6+18+\cdots + 2\cdot 3^{n-1} = 2\cdot 3^{n}-1\quad$(compare with $(\star)$)
- Case $n+1$ (to be shown): $2+6+18+\cdots + 2\cdot 3^{n} \stackrel{?}{=} 2\cdot 3^{n+1}-1\quad$(compare with $(\star\star)$)
- Proof of Case $n+1$ using Case $n$:
  $$\begin{align}
  2+6+18+\cdots + 2\cdot 3^{n}
  &= 2+6+18+\cdots + 2\cdot 3^{n-1} + 2\cdot 3^{n} \\
  &= \left(\;\; 3^{n}-1 \;\;\right) + 2\cdot 3^{n} \\
  &= (2+1)\cdot 3^n - 1 \\
  &\stackrel{\ddot\smile}{=} 3^{n+1} - 1
  \end{align}$$

So, now we've built a magic induction machine that will spread the validity of the formula from any $n$ to the *next* $n$. We just have to feed the machine a *first* $n$ ---that is, *the* first $n$--- by proving that the formula holds in the dead-simple case of $n=1$.

- Case $1$: $\quad 2\cdot 3^{1-1} \stackrel{?}{=} 3^{1}-1$
- (Overly-pedantic*) Proof of Case $1$: $\quad 2\cdot 3^{1-1} = 2 \cdot 3^0 = 2 \cdot 1 = 2 = 3 - 1 \stackrel{\ddot\smile}{=} 3^1-1$

*In real mathematical life (as opposed to *imaginary* mathematical life?), we usually just say "The base case is obvious."

And there you have it. Thanks to our magic induction machine, what's true for $n=1$ is true for $n=2$; and what's true for $n=2$ is true for $n=3$; and what's true for $n=3$ is true for $n=4$; and so on, and so on, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(n): 2+6+18+\cdots+2(3^{n-1})=3^n-1$

So, $P(1):2= 3^1-1$ which is true

Let $P(m)$ is true i.e., $2+6+18+\cdots+2(3^{m-1})=3^m-1$

$P(m+1):$  $2+6+18+\cdots+2(3^{m-1})+2\cdot 3^m=3^m-1+2\cdot 3^m=(1+2)3^m-1=3^{m+1}-1$

So,  $P(m+1)$ will hole true if $P(m)$ is true

But, we have already shown $P(n)$ is true for $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

The "base step" isn't to prove that it is true for "$n$"... it is to prove that it is true for the *first positive integer*.

So, in this case, you want to start off by proving that it is true for $n=1$; that is, that $2=3^1-1$.  (Not too hard of a base case, right?)

Now, the idea is this:  ASSUMING that for some number $n$ you know it is true, show that it is also true for the next number.

Answer (score 0):

If you needn't insist on applying the mathematical induction, there exists another proof for this which is more simple.

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2 \cdot 3^{k-1}=2+6+18+\dots+2\cdot 3^{n-1}.$$Then, we obtain $$3S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2 \cdot 3^{k}=6+18+54+\dots+2\cdot 3^{n}.$$ The one below minus the above gives that $$2S_n=2 \cdot 3^{n}-2.$$As a result,$$S_n=3^n-1.$$